# Logitech K780 Keyboard Connection via BLuetooth

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

I have a Pi 3 and I am trying to connect a K780 keyboard. I have used the terminal and the GUI to connect, pair and trust the keyboard. However, the K780 never gets out of pair mode. It seems as though it is waiting for some kind of command to unpair it.

The keyboard easily pairs and works normally on other computers.  With the Pi, I never get to a point where I have to type the pin code on the K780 keyboard. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread but I had the same issue, found this thread, spent a few hours and found a solution.  Then got another pi and completely forgot how to fix the issue, and had to search again.  Figured id post the solution here this time.

Found a solution here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=171456

The issue is with BLE devices. The following from jonathancorrin worked for me:

> Reboot the pi
>   open terminal window and type the following lines:
>
> ```
> sudo hciconfig hci0 down
> sudo hciconfig hci0 up
> bluetoothctl
> scan on
> ```
>
> Press the discovery button on the bluetooth device, the device should popup >in the terminal along with its bluetooth address, then type the following >where X is the bluetooth address :
>
> ```
> pair X
> ```
>
> A dialogue box should popup stating that the bluetooth device would like to >connect, press connect and then the ok button on the next popup.

I did however have to reboot my pi an additional time after these steps.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue too, I use the method below to setup the keyboard and MX Ergo mouse.

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# pair MAC_ADDRESS
[bluetooth]# quit
```

If the bluetooth daemon stopped. You may use the script below to start the bluetooth daemon.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

I think the key is to shut down the keyboard and mouse and try several times to make them connected.